# Integrating Room Persistence Library with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, android-room

Fairly new in Android Studio, and I want to make an app with a chart that would update real time based on data retrieved from the database. The gist of it is to store some Coordinates into the database and have the chart update based on the contents of the database. So far, I made one, based on what I learned from [this tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0), and in the MPAndroidChart wiki, tutorial and sample codes. The only thing I did differently to integrate the two was to ditch the adapter (since I don't know what its equivalent in MPAndroidChart) and RecyclerView, since it's a chart. It works, but there are a few bugs that I can't seem to solve.

1.) When I run it the first time, it's okay, adding Coordinates (the object I use for storing in the database) instantly updates the chart. But when I run the app again, with the previous data stored, the chart won't update right away, and the chart is basically frozen until after 10 or so entries have been entered. Sometimes it doesn't update after all.

2.) Sometimes there is an artifact line coming out of the first point (so there's a line between points generated, and then there's this other line going nowhere, like this) It only happens on the second run, and so on.

Any ideas as to where I have gone wrong? I think it's the adapter part; but I don't know how to make it with MPAndroidChart.. :/

EDIT: Here's some of my code. Most of it is almost the same from the Room tutorial, but with the Coordinates object instead.

Here's what it does onChanged, in MainActivity.java:

```
        mCoordinatesViewModel.getAllCoordinates().observe(this, new Observer<List<Coordinates>> () {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable final List<Coordinates> coordinates){
            if (coordinates != null && !coordinates.isEmpty()) { updateChart(coordinates); }
        }
    });
```

The updateChart function:

```
    private void updateChart(List<Coordinates> coordinates){
    TextView displayViewNum = (TextView) textViewNum;

    LineData data = chartMain.getData();
    ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

    if (set == null){
        set = createSet();
        data.addDataSet(set);
    }

    if (firstEntry) {
        set.removeFirst();
        firstEntry = false;
    }

    // retrieve from database
    int dx = (int) coordinates.get(coordinates.size() - 1).getX();
    float dy = (float) coordinates.get(coordinates.size() - 1).getY();

    String text = "(" + dx + ", " + dy + ")";
    displayViewNum.setText(text);

    // add to data as Entry
    Entry entry = new Entry(dx, dy);
    data.addEntry(entry, 0);

    data.notifyDataChanged();
    chartMain.notifyDataSetChanged();

    chartMain.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
    chartMain.moveViewToX(data.getEntryCount());

}
```

I don't know what code to post anymore without making this very long. So I'll just edit this along the way if there are replies.

Thanks!

EDIT: Pinned down the core problem as that the app has no way of loading previous data from the database. I tried making this function:

```
 private void initializeChart(List<Coordinates> coordinates){
    LineData data = chartMain.getData();
    ILineDataSet set = data.getDataSetByIndex(0);

    if (set == null){
        set = createSet();
        data.addDataSet(set);
    }

    if (firstEntry) {
        set.removeFirst();
        firstEntry = false;
    }

    // retrieve from database
    for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {
        int dx = (int) coordinates.get(i).getX();
        float dy = (float) coordinates.get(i).getY();

        // add to data as Entry
        Entry entry = new Entry(dx, dy);
        data.addEntry(entry, 0);

        data.notifyDataChanged();
        chartMain.notifyDataSetChanged();

        chartMain.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(10);
        chartMain.moveViewToX(data.getEntryCount());
    }

}
```

And called it on the onCreate function like this:

```
initializeChart(mCoordinatesViewModel.getAllCoordinates().getValue());
```

But now it still crashes. Is there a way to get previous data, if there are any, from Room database, at startup? I guess I could figure out updating the chart from there.

Here is something that came out of logcat; red text has been italicized instead:

`07-08 10:44:07.660 246-246/? I/auditd: type=1403 audit(0.0:2): policy loaded auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
07-08 10:44:07.660 246-246/? W/auditd: type=1404 audit(0.0:3): enforcing=1 old_enforcing=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295
07-08 10:44:08.180 1-1/? W/init: type=1400 audit(0.0:4): avc: denied { create } for name="preload" scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
    type=1400 audit(0.0:5): avc: denied { create } for name="preload" scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
07-08 10:44:08.950 1-1/? W/init: type=1400 audit(0.0:6): avc: denied { create } for name="root_channel" scontext=u:r:init:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:root_execute_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
07-08 10:44:09.090 248-248/? I//system/bin/tzdatacheck: tzdata file /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/tzdata does not exist. No action required.`

```
--------- beginning of system
```

07-08 10:44:09.113 247-247/? I/vold: Vold 3.0 (the awakening) firing up
07-08 10:44:09.113 247-256/? D/NVRAM: Check whether nvram restore ready!
07-08 10:44:09.114 247-247/? V/vold: Detected support for: exfat ext4 vfat exfat
07-08 10:44:09.131 247-247/? D/vold: EncfsVolume(encfs) is newed
07-08 10:44:09.138 247-247/? W/Vold: Tearing down stale mount /mnt/cd-rom
07-08 10:44:09.138 247-247/? D/vold: EmulatedVolume(emulated) is newed
07-08 10:44:09.147 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.147 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop0'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=0'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop0'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.147 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.147 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop1'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=1'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop1'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.147 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.147 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop2'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=2'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop2'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop3'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=3'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop3'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop4'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=4'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop4'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop5'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=5'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop5'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.148 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop6'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=6'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop6'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/loop7'
    NL param 'MAJOR=7'
    NL param 'MINOR=7'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=loop7'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/virtual/block/zram0'
    NL param 'MAJOR=254'
    NL param 'MINOR=0'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=zram0'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0rpmb'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=96'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0rpmb'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? D/vold: Skip 'mmcblk0rpmb' disk uevent
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.149 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0boot0'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=32'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0boot0'
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? D/vold: Skip 'mmcblk0boot0' disk uevent
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0boot1'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=64'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0boot1'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? D/vold: Skip 'mmcblk0boot1' disk uevent
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=0'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=20'
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? I/Vold: handleBlockEvent(): For MTK_SHARED_SDCARD, remove EMMC disk
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p1'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=1'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p1'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=1'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=proinfo'
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.150 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p2'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=2'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p2'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=2'
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL param 'PARTNAME=nvram'
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p3'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=3'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p3'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=3'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=protect1'
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p4'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=4'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p4'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=4'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=protect2'
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p5'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=5'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p5'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=5'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=seccfg'
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p6'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=6'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p6'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=6'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=lk'
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p7'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=7'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p7'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=7'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=boot'
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.151 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p8'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=8'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p8'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL param 'PARTN=8'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=recovery'
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p9'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=9'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p9'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=9'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=secro'
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0rpmb'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=96'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0rpmb'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/vold: Skip 'mmcblk0rpmb' disk uevent
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0boot0'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=32'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0boot0'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/vold: Skip 'mmcblk0boot0' disk uevent
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0boot1'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=64'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0boot1'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=0'
07-08 10:44:09.152 247-257/? D/vold: Skip 'mmcblk0boot1' disk uevent
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p10'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=10'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p10'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=10'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=para'
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p11'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=11'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p11'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=11'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=logo'
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p12'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=12'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p12'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=12'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=expdb'
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p13'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=13'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p13'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=13'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=tee1'
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p14'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=14'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p14'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=14'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=tee2'
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.153 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p15'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=15'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p15'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=15'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=metadata'
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p16'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=16'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p16'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=16'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=frp'
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p17'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=17'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p17'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=17'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=system'
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p18'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=18'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p18'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=18'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=cache'
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p19'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=19'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p19'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=19'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=userdata'
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11230000.MSDC0/mmc_host/mmc0/mmc0:0001/block/mmcblk0/mmcblk0p20'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=20'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk0p20'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=partition'
    NL param 'PARTN=20'
    NL param 'PARTNAME=flashinfo'
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? V/vold: ----------------
    handleBlockEvent with action 1
07-08 10:44:09.154 247-257/? D/NetlinkEvent: NL action '1'
    NL subsystem 'block'
    NL param 'DEVPATH=/devices/mtk-msdc.0/11240000.MSDC1/mmc_host/mmc1/mmc1:b368/block/mmcblk1'
    NL param 'MAJOR=179'
    NL param 'MINOR=128'
    NL param 'DEVNAME=mmcblk1'
    NL param 'DEVTYPE=disk'
    NL param 'NPARTS=2'
07-08 10:44:09.155 247-247/? I/NVRAM: Coldboot: try to wait for uevents, timeout 5s
07-08 10:44:09.157 247-257/? V/vold: /system/bin/sgdisk
        --android-dump
        /dev/block/vold/disk:179,128
07-08 10:44:09.191 247-257/? V/vold: DISK gpt 948990E6-7A6A-48F0-8125-902ABB436A97
07-08 10:44:09.192 247-257/? V/vold: PART 1 19A710A2-B3CA-11E4-B026-10604B889DCF 2A1B6584-97AE-4993-9940-CEA6DFEAD900 android_meta
    PART 2 193D1EA4-B3CA-11E4-B075-10604B889DCF AE7C2709-9D38-6E0E-8D32-5B4C685CF3C0 android_expand
07-08 10:44:09.193 247-257/? D/vold: Found key for GUID ae7c27099d386e0e8d325b4c685cf3c0
    PrivateVolume(private:179,130) is newed
*07-08 10:44:09.194 247-257/? E/Cryptfs: Cannot remove dm-crypt device, retry(0), rtn(-1)
07-08 10:44:09.694 247-257/? E/Cryptfs: Cannot remove dm-crypt device, retry(1), rtn(-1)*
07-08 10:55:02.364 1288-1288/? D/wpa_supplicant: nl80211: Event message available

Comment: The question is too broad right now, you'll have to learn debugging and find out what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Should I remake the question? The main problem is just the proper loading of the data left from the database to the viewModel. I realized the app has no way to load previous data; I tried making a function that will retrieve last session's data and update the chart from it at startup, but it crashed.

Comment: Are you calling the Room queries on a background thread? Try adding `.allowMainThreadQueries()` and see if that fixes the issue (but you definitely want to use background threads and not leave it that way)

Comment: Just tried it, doesn't do anything different.

Comment: If your question is about a crash, then we need a stack trace.

Comment: Updated it; added what's in logcat; since it doesn't produce a stack trace, only those two red lines that doesn't make much sense..